# Passing string value to viewcontroller but getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to print (nslog) the name of a photo embedded in PhotoView object that I created. I have created 2 viewcontrollers class and the PhotoView class extending the UIButton class to populate a grid in one of the former viewcontrollers.

In PhotoView.h I have

```
@interface PhotoView : UIButton
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *photoName;
...
```

in PhotoView.m I have

```
    self.tag = [[data objectForKey:@"PhotoID"] intValue];
    self.photoName = [data objectForKey:@"PhotoName"];
```

After printing out the value of tag and photoName on the same file, everything looks good.

Problem start when I try to print the value of photoName from another class after clicking on the PhotoView

```
-(void)didSelectPhoto:(PhotoView*)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender.photoName]);
}
```

After clicking on the photoView, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

However, If I do

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag]])
```

I don't get this error.

What could possibly be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two remarks:

1. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sender.photoName]` - ***No please! No! Don't do that!*** It's not only superfluous and wastes CPU cycles, but it also heavily decreases readability. if you have a string, you don't have to duplicate it like this, just use the string object directly:

---

```
NSLog(@"%@", sender.photoName);
```

1. The actual error you have is this:

---

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *photoName;
```

I. e. you have an `assign` property, so it doesn't retain its value. When your string object goes out of scope, it's deallocated (and since it's not `weak`, it isn't automatically set to `nil`, but it holds whatever garbage value that invalid pointer is, hence the crash). Write instead

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *photoName;
```

if you're not using ARC, and

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *photoName;
```

if you are.

Comment: You state "`assign`, a.k.a `weak`". Actually, `weak` and `assign` have a key difference. It shouldn't be implied that they are the same. Also, may I suggest you update your first remark with the proper code. It's one thing to explain that it is wrong and why, but it would be even more helpful to show the proper usage.

Comment: @rmaddy Fair points, thank you for the advice. Looked up the difference, fixed code.

Comment: Thank you guys for the solution to my problem. I have never paid attention to these attributes, only followed the tutorials blindly. Now I am going to read about all the possible attributes that a property can have. Thanks again.